# Is there any way to get selected values from ManyToManyField before save in Django Model

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I've a model with many-to-many field. And I want to pre-process the values that will be selected on the many-to-many field. I need help from the experts. Thanks in advance.

I've already tried to solve according to my scenario. But it's not working what I want.
My code is given below:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='sku'.upper())
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='title'.title())
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    .....

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       selected_categories = self.category.all()
    ......
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

Comment: Entries in an m2m cannot possibly exist before save. If you need to pre-process them, you need to do it in the form or the view.